# How to load just the last record from entity with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity, datamodel

I want to fetch value of field named "Gram" from the last record and put its value into a variable, without using any conditions.

First I tried

```
int value = int.Parse(Entity.TblGold.LastOrDefault().Gram.ToString());
```

Second I tried

```
int value = int.Parse(Entity.TblGold.Select(p => p.Gram).Last().ToString());
```

I just receive this exception:

> ``` LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'DataModel.TblGold LastOrDefault[TblGold](System.Linq.IQueryable``1[DataModel.TblGold])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. ```

Comment: Side note: there is generally no concept of "last" record in databases... Only "last, when sorted by field(s)".

Comment: There Should be a solution.I Have my table in my Entity.for example 200 records...and i want a value of special field just from LAST record.there is no condition.so how can i grab this value from field????? :(

Comment: Can you suggest me Code Please, i'm really sorry to disturb you time

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Last` or `LastOrDefault` are not supported in LINQ to Entities. You can either iterate your query using `ToList` or `ToArray` and then apply `Last` or you can order by descending and then use the `First` like:

```
int value = int.Parse(Entity.TblGold
                            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Gram)
                            .Select(r => r.Gram)
                            .First().ToString());
```

Comment: @amin, you are welcome and I see you joined today, Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: It's kind of you :) Thank you very much.
So as i figure it out,we should have some kind of instance to do last or first or like these?

Comment: @amin, not really, for First, it gets translated into `SELECT Top (1)` So you don't really have to iterate the query. The above query in answer is getting translated into something like `SELECT TOP 1 Gram from tblGold Order by Gram DESC;` . With `Last/LastOrDefault` the expression can't translate into under laying data source language (SQL).

Comment: @amin, sorry I missed the part for selecting a particular field. Just check the updated answer

Comment: It really helped me out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an incremental id:

```
int idx = tb.Max(i => i.Id);
var row = tb.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in one query, but you can do it in two.

```
var countOfRows = tbl.Count();

var lastRow = tbl.Skip(countOfRows - 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: your code doesn't compile because off an error for nothing stored or use orderby

Answer (score 0):

It is your answer and you don't need to convert.

```
int value = Entity.TblGold.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).First().Gram;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use order by 1 == 1 and it works

```
var countOfRows = tbl.Count();    
var lastRow = tbl.OrderBy(c => 1 == 1).Skip(countOfRows - 1).FirstOrDefault();
```